# php show div element when POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to show the progress bar when I click the button submit. Below is the code, when I click the button the console is printing the message but, the `div` element `converting_prog` is not showing.

What wrong with below code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <?php
            //process the forms and upload the files
            if ($_POST) {
                //specify folder for file upload
                $user = $_GET["user"];
                ?>
                <script>
                    console.log("posting...");
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('converting_prog').style.display = 'block';</script>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outPopUp">
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
                <input class="btn" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
            <div id="converting_prog" class="progress" style="display:none; margin-right:20px;margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px;width:auto">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
                    Converting %
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can shift script after converting_prog element.

Comment: In general is a good practice to put all `<script>` code on the bottom at your page right before closing the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it runs, the DOM hasn't loaded yet. Try moving the whole PHP `if` block to the end of the page, so that the JS can run later.

Or you could wrap that script in a `window.onload = function(){}` handler.

Comment: Yes moving the the POST checking to end of the page solved the problem.

Comment: Why not doing it on server side?

Comment: @MilanG Do what on the server side? I offered one solution -- you can (and i see you did) offer an alternate.

Comment: I see no point on always printing HTML and then hiding from JS based on condition which is also available on server side (php).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are detecting post button after form is submitted (unusual) then at time when page is generated you already know if form is submitted or not. Because of that you don't need that JS code to hide the block - just simply don't print it when it's not needed.

```
if (!$_POST) {
?>
  <div id= "converting_prog" class="progress" style="margin-right:20px;margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px;width:auto">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
      Converting %
    </div>

</div>
<?php 
}
```

So just add that if around your existing progress bar code.

Comment: I think it would make sense to only print the div `if ($_POST)`, and then without the `display:none`.

Comment: Now it'll only print before you click submit.

Comment: It was more the idea - to check $_POST array and depending on it's value print or not that extra block. I didn't have environment to test it. But if you are going to use it do some extra work. Print out $_POST, see what you have when page is opened first time and what when form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code between your script tags :

```
document.getElementById("id of your button").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("converting_prog").style.display = "block";});
```

Answer (score 1):

I change your $_POST checking status and position with following code which is working fine :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="outPopUp">
         <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
            <input class="btn" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
         </form>
         <div id= "converting_prog" class="progress" style="display:none; margin-right:20px;margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px;width:auto">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
               Converting %
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
<?php
//process the forms and upload the files
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    //specify folder for file upload
    //$user = $_GET["user"];
    ?>
  <script>
     $('#converting_prog').show();
  </script> 
  <?php
} ?>
```